# React object property assignment only works the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

For the following code, parameters are js objects whose structures are initialized as follows:

```
statePiece = {
  field_name: { disabled: false, exampleValue: "arbitrary" },
  field_name2: {
    /* ... */
  },
  field_nameN: {
    /* ... */
  }
};

userField = "field_name_string";

sesarValues = {
  format: "one2one",
  selectedField: "latitude",
  disabledSelf: true,
  addField: 0
};
```

This function works correctly and returns the modified `statePiece` as `returnTemp` the first time a particular `statePiece.field_name` is modified

```
export let setUserField = (statePiece, userField, sesarValues) => {
  console.log("set user field", userField, "set mappval", sesarValues);

  var temp = { ...statePiece }; //(this.state.fields[each].mappedTo != null) ? (this.state.fields[userField].mappedTo) : [];
  var XUnit = statePiece[userField];

  if (typeof userField != "string") {
    console.log("not string");
    for (var each of userField) {
      if (sesarValues) {
        temp[each].mappedTo = sesarValues.selectedField;
        temp[each].disabled = true;
      } else {
        temp[each].disabled = !temp[each].disabled;
        delete temp[each].mappedTo;
      }
    }
  } else {
    //is string
    console.log("is string");
    console.log(XUnit);

    if (sesarValues) {
      if (XUnit.disabled === true) XUnit.disabled = false;
      console.log("1");
      console.log(XUnit);

      XUnit.disabled = true;
      console.log(XUnit);
      XUnit.mappedTo = sesarValues.selectedField;
    } else {
      console.log("2");
      temp[userField].disabled = !temp[userField].disabled;
      delete temp[userField].mappedTo;
    }
  }
  let returnTemp = { ...temp, [userField]: XUnit };
  console.log("set UF debug ", returnTemp);
  console.log(returnTemp["FACILITY_CODE"]);
  return returnTemp;
};
```

But after that, changing the `statePiece.userField.mappedTo` value fails to alter the object property. Or at least alter it permanently. When I console log the `returnTemp` variable, I see the entry has lost its `mappedTo` entry(as should happen) without it being replaced with the new `userField`.

However, when I `console.log(returnTemp[userField])` it shows the entry values with the expected `mappedTo` key: value pair.

Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Do you update the state using `this.setState({...})`??

Answer (score 0):

From the usage of `userField`, I can work out that it could be an `Array` or a `String`.

However you have done something curious with it in the following expression:

```
var XUnit = statePiece[userField];
```

Given `userField` is a `String`, the above expression is fine. 
However, where it is an array, `XUnit` will be `undefined`.

Also doing the same where `userField` is an `Array` in the following line means that you're setting the `userField.toString()` as a key mapped to `undefined`.

```
let returnTemp = { ...temp, [userField]: XUnit };
```

I'd assign `XUnit` where the condition checks out that `userField` is a `String` and just return `temp`.

```
else {
    //is string
    var XUnit = statePiece[userField];
    //...
}
return temp;
```